# Original El Capitan 10.11.0?

Tags: macos, mac

I'm looking to upgrade my Yosemite system with El Capitan but I can only find 10.11.1 versions. Need the original. Any help? Any thoughts?

Comment: All ElCaps 10.11.0-10.11.6 once available - only 10.11.6 is still there if you have downloaded it before - at the Apple App Store are "original" system installers!

Comment: Why would you want 10.11.0?

Comment: to be clear, I want to install the latest, pre-Sierra OS. I tried to upload ElCap 10.11.1 "upgrade" and the program told me I could not activate without having first installed the original. I would be satisfied installing ElCap 10.11.6 and wait on Sierra for a while if possible. Thanks for the responses to date,

Comment: @Tom you are probably talking of the [10.11.1 update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1845?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). That's just an updater from 10.11.0 to 10.11.1. You can't upgrade from Yosemite to El Capitan with that one . Simply download 10.11.6 (>5 GB) from the App Store.

Comment: @Tom, if you don't see OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 in the App Store you can get it from the link in [How to download OS X El Capitan from the App Store even if never downloaded before macOS Sierra was released or purchased is grayed out](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257591/how-to-download-os-x-el-capitan-from-the-app-store-even-if-never-downloaded-befo), which will bring it up in the App Store for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you "purchased" El Capitan during it's availability you can download it from the App Store in the usual way. You will actually get 10.11.6 - there are no reasons to install 10.11.0, and Apple does not have an all-versions archive.

If you did not get El Capitan while it was available then you can't get it. Sierra is the current offering, but wait a few weeks for 10.12.1.

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't serve up downloads of older builds of OS from the Mac App Store, so you will have to save your copies for reuse as they are current. I would try downloading whatever version of OS X from the App Store you have.

Even a paid developer can't easily re-download older versions (say 10.11.0 instead of 10.11.6). There are previous versions available for download, but they mostly are the most up to date version of 10.11.6, 10.10.5, 10.9.5 etc... and not an exhaustive list of each build.

If you really need it, contacting Apple Developer relations might work to get a specific build for a specific reason. This will likely cost money to be a paid developer and you might not succeed in convincing them you need an expired / patched build of the OS. Hopefully they would help as your other alternative is to find a copy on the internet which is liable to be one that's tampered with if you don't check carefully checksums of the download. People have seeded malicious "Apple" installers and shared them online, so the risk isn't academic to getting more than you requested with a third party download.