# Macbook pro - resetting NVRAM

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

My 2010 MacBook Pro is stuck at the Apple logo and spinner (followed by a circle with a line through it). I accidentally mis-typed and altered the NVRAM setting. (as this `sudo nvrm "rd=wrognserver"`). I have already tried <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, to no avail (but suspect the keyboard is not working, I have ordered a wired USB keyboard, awaiting delivery). Any clues would be helpful.

Comment: This is not an NVRAM issue - you are missing a boot device:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/271683/119271

Comment: Thanks Alan, Here is a bit more detail on the reason for suspecting NVRAM params.

Comment: Hold Option while you boot.  It will force the boot loader to scan all attached volumes for bootable partitions.  A wrong variable will get ignored so what you entered has no effect.  You can also delete it by issuing the command `nvram -d rd`

Comment: Thanks Alan for the quick response, I tried cmd +R with the OSX install Cd, which came with the MacBook Pro. I also tried to restore from the time machine backup (cmd+R) but no vail. Originally the command I used is  : sudo nvram -d boot-args="rd=xysnsms" && sudo reboot. The reboot failed immediately after this command.

Comment: did you hold `option`?

Comment: yep, tried that first.

Comment: Something more was done.  than just changing boot arguments.  Boot into Internet Recovery.  Hold `Cmd-Opt-R` and it should download the Recovery OS for you,

Comment: Will try that today!