# Install El Captain

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I just purchased an older Mac from someone. It was working fine and El Captain 10.11 was installed.  I wanted to wipe it with all the junk they had on it.  I did the erase and booted to Recovery Mode but it won't install the software as it says it's not on the Apple Store.  I tried to download it through iTunes but it says it's not available in Canada.

Would love some help.  I am thinking I have to do it via USB but need some help finding the right file to use and how to create the USB on my Windows 7 PC.

Comment: You can download the macOS installation from the Mac App Store. It won't require signing in and should be accessible in Canada.

Comment: Nope have tried it all Shift+Command+R and all others, it wants to continue loading el captain which it cant get from the app store

Comment: Related or duplicate: [Can not download el Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282798/can-not-download-el-capitan). AFAIK you can't create a macOS installer thumb drive on a WIndows machine.

Comment: Re using a PC to create a bootable Mac USB, refer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/142169

Comment: Also related - [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)

Comment: Which Mac is it? Could you post the model number?