# MacBook Pro Fin 2008 10.10 Upgrade issue

Tags: macos, ios, ssd, upgrade, memory

I have Mac Pro 17 Inch running 10.10 Yosemite OS, I've made some Hardware changes such as replacing HDD with SSD and increasing RAM slots, moreover, I'd like to upgrade from 10.10 **Yosemite** to 10.11 **El Capital** but this went wrong, after I downloaded the DMG file from the official apple site, trying to install it, I got an error which describes that this operation cannot be made since Apple no longer offer an update for those old machines
the error says "This Update Requires OS X version 10.11" as shown in the attached screen-shot

[image: the error shown during the installation!]

Comment: See also - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos

Answer (score 2):

You've downloaded an updater for an existing installation of El Capitan. You need a complete OS installer.

[How to download OS X El Capitan from the App Store even if never downloaded before macOS Sierra was released or purchased is grayed out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257591/how-to-download-os-x-el-capitan-from-the-app-store-even-if-never-downloaded-befo)